# Error: could not find function "selectizeInput"

Tags: r, shiny

I am using selectizeInout in my shiny app and I am getting following error message:

"Error: could not find function "selectizeInput""

I am using following code i n my server.R code but I am getting above error message.

```
output$Choose_Molecule <- renderUI({
selectizeInput(
  'molecule', 'Select Molecule:', choices = ArgNames(),
  options = list(
    placeholder = 'Please select an option below',
    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
  )
)
})
```

I went through https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/412 . I am giving following information:

```
    > library('shiny')
> pre(paste(capture.output(sessionInfo()), collapse='\n'))
<pre>R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_US
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US     LC_MONETARY=en_US    LC_MESSAGES=en_US
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.9.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6  caTools_1.17  digest_0.6.4  httpuv_1.3.0  Rcpp_0.11.1
[6] RJSONIO_1.0-3 xtable_1.7-3 </pre>

> pre(find.package('shiny'))
<pre>/home/vxy342/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/shiny</pre>

> pre(paste(readLines(system.file('DESCRIPTION', package='shiny')), collapse='\n'))
<pre>Package: shiny
Type: Package
Title: Web Application Framework for R
Version: 0.9.1
Date: 2014-03-19
Author: RStudio, Inc.
Maintainer: Winston Chang &lt;winston@rstudio.com&gt;
Description: Shiny makes it incredibly easy to build interactive web
    applications with R. Automatic "reactive" binding between inputs and
    outputs and extensive pre-built widgets make it possible to build
    beautiful, responsive, and powerful applications with minimal effort.
License: GPL-3
Depends: R (&gt;= 2.14.1), methods
Imports: stats, tools, utils, httpuv (&gt;= 1.2.0), caTools, RJSONIO,
        xtable, digest
Suggests: datasets, markdown, Cairo (&gt;= 1.5-5), testthat
URL: http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/
BugReports: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues
Collate: 'bootstrap-layout.R' 'bootstrap.R' 'cache.R' 'map.R'
        'fileupload.R' 'graph.R' 'hooks.R' 'imageutils.R' 'jqueryui.R'
        'priorityqueue.R' 'react.R' 'reactives.R' 'run-url.R'
        'sessioncontext.R' 'utils.R' 'shiny.R' 'shinyui.R'
        'shinywrappers.R' 'showcase.R' 'slider.R' 'tags.R' 'tar.R'
        'timer.R' 'update-input.R'
Packaged: 2014-03-19 18:50:47 UTC; ubuntu
NeedsCompilation: no
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2014-03-19 20:56:50
Built: R 3.0.1; ; 2014-04-25 03:09:38 UTC; unix</pre>
>
```

Comment: how is this related with java?

Comment: I have read something about shiny selectizeInput and it usage jave. I refer "https://demo.shinyapps.io/013-selectize/". But I think this is not the JAVA issue. I mention since java is related with this function.

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue. I can call `selectizeInput` just fine from "server.R" inside a `renderUI` call. Perhaps you can supply a more concrete example that will reproduce the error. You do have `library(shiny)` in your server.R file, right?

Comment: And that page makes reference to "javascript", not "java". Those are two very different languages.

Comment: Yes I have used library(shiny) in both. server.R and ui.R.

Comment: Do you think, what I mention in my code "onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')" is corrcet? ==> I am getting help from "https://demo.shinyapps.io/013-selectize/"

Comment: @tinku It worked for me. At this point it sounds like you have some other syntax error going on. Unless you can create a minimally reproducible example, it is unlikely we will be able to help you further.